# How to implement JSTree properly on Lightning Web Components?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I've successfully integrated JSTree on LWC. But, it is not working properly. The connections between the nodes aren't shown. I've used the following JSON format to pass data:

```
const element = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="dataTree"]');

//let myTree=this.template.find('#jstree_demo');
//console.log("ele2:", ele2);
// 6 create an instance when the DOM is ready
$(element).jstree({
  core: {
    data: [
      { id: "ajson1", parent: "#", text: "Simple root node" },
      { id: "ajson2", parent: "#", text: "Root node 2" },
      { id: "ajson3", parent: "ajson2", text: "Child 1" },
      { id: "ajson4", parent: "ajson2", text: "Child 2" }
    ]
  }
});
```

And the output is shown below:

[image] [image]

So, it's working but the linkage/connection between the nodes isn't. Could anyone please help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Did you import the related CSS? Also, why not just use the native lightning-tree instead?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, I didn't import any CSS, I don't know about it, gonna recheck then! Btw, I've already a VSPage implemented using JSTree, that's why trying to transform it to the LWC for more flexibility.

Comment: hey HasanOnM, what solution did you end up with?